# Is there a word which matches 'progress(ing)' and 'regress(ing)' but means no change?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a visually similar i.e. ending in '*gress(ing)*' word which means '*no change has occurred'* as opposed to '*progress*' and '*regress*' which both show either positive or negative progression.

The example case would be a notification message outlining score change:

> Your score is (progressing|requested-word-for-no-change|regressing).

Comment: Only word I can think of with that meaning is "stagnating". I don't think there is a word that matches your request.

Comment: @TimFoster funnily enough, that's the word I'm using right now.

Comment: since the element 'gress' means 'go', 'walk', the idea of 'no change' is of 'not going', 'not walking', that is 'staying', 'remaining', 'stagnating'... There is no such thing as 'nulli-gressing', or 'no-gressing', or 'a-gressing', where the 'a' would be the Greek negative prefix and not the Latin prefix 'ad', which we have in 'aggress', 'walk towards someone, against someone'

Comment: the closest thing to an answer to your question would be 'treading water', or 'tread milling', if it existed, where the person is still moving, doing something, 'gressing', has not come to a standstill, but is doing it to no avail

Comment: If you really want '-gress' and are ready for a humorous note, then walking without moving either forward or back is walking in circles: so "My dear, I am afraid you are/your score is cyclo-gressing!"

Answer (score 1):

"Your score is (progressing / [**unchanging**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unchanging) / regressing)."

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : CONSTANT, INVARIABLE unchanging beliefs

This word avoids the kinds of association in meaning that would be provided by words such as *staying* and *languishing*. It's a simple fact that the score is remaining constant.